# Docker image with Maven fails to run

Tags: maven, docker

I want to use Maven in my Docker image.

After looking here https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/, I tried using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:7

RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.3.9
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
    | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

COPY mvn-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh
COPY settings-docker.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/

VOLUME "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mvn"]
```

However, I'm getting:

```
lstat mvn-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
```

I tried different Dockerfiles from the same repositories but they all throw this error.

What's wrong with this dockerfile?
How can I use Maven with Docker?

Comment: Are you on windows? If yes check EOL. And do you have `mvn-entrypoint.sh` located in correct folder?

Comment: I'm on Windows but I'm using the Docker terminal so I guess it's not an EOL issue.

Comment: Also, I never go inside the docker container, I'm only trying to construct it from the image, so I don't think there is an issue with being in the incorrect folder.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, I have forgotten to download the "mvn-entrypoint.sh" file.. https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/tree/322d0dff5d0531ccaf47bf49338cb3e294fd66c8/jdk-8 .. also the settings-docker.xml was required..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Dockerfile:-

```
FROM openjdk:8u111-jdk-alpine

COPY assets/settings.xml /tmp/settings.xml
ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/maven/bin

RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar bash && \
  curl -SsL -o /tmp/maven.tar.gz http://www-us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz && \
  mkdir -p /opt && \
  tar xzf /tmp/maven.tar.gz -C /opt/ && \
  ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9 /opt/maven && \
  rm /tmp/maven.tar.gz && \
  mv /tmp/settings.xml /opt/maven/conf/settings.xml
```

You need to put this Dockerfile in a new directory, with a subdirectory called 'assets', and you need to put a maven settings file (`settings.xml`) in that directory. If you don't have a custom settings file then remove the `COPY` and the `mv`.

Build it with something like

```
docker --tag ajava8 .
```

You can run maven in your current directory using something like:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /$PWD:/work -w /work ajava8 mvn clean install
```

Or, you can get a bash shell with something similar, like this:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /$PWD:/work -w /work ajava8 bash
```

Comment: It fails with this message: `Sending build context to Docker daemon 191.5 kB
Step 1 : FROM openjdk:7
 ---> b3776fe72f6c
Step 2 : COPY assets/settings.xml /tmp/settings.xml
lstat assets/settings.xml: no such file or directory`

Comment: If I remove the `COPY` and the `move`: `/bin/sh: 1: apk: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache curl tar bash &&   curl -SsL -o /tmp/maven.tar.gz http://www-us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz &&   mkdir -p /opt &&   tar xzf /tmp/maven.tar.gz -C /opt/ &&   ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9 /opt/maven &&   rm /tmp/maven.tar.gz' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: Ok, try it now -- I've changed the version for the openjdk. I've just run this and it works fine on my machine, which is a windows laptop running the latest version of docker tools.

Answer (score 0):

You need the files copied in the Dockerfile `mvn-entrypoint.sh` and `settings-docker.xml`. 
You can git clone from https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven

Comment: I'm facing same issue, can you guide me where to put these two files?

Comment: in the same dir as the Dockerfile